# Import data from file larger than 15 MB

Tags: import

I have my blog on wordpress.com, I want it to be moved on self hosted server.

I have exported data from my wordpress.com blog to XML file, However, When I went to import the data to my self hosted wordpress installation it says file must not be greater than 15MB and my file is of `2257 MB`

How do I go to import such a large file?

Answer (score 0):

you should try splitting the file with [this tool](http://www.rangerpretzel.com/content/view/20/1/). I used it several years ago and hopefully it still works with the current export file format.

After splitting you import each of the generated files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing the max upload size of wp???
you can increase it many ways given below are few
Adding following code in theme’s functions.php file, you can increase the upload size:

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

Create or Edit an existing PHP.INI file

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

htaccess Method

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

Comment: this is helpfule